# data source does not support server-side data paging

Tags: asp.net

i am currently trying to do paging for my gridview but once i allow paging in my gridview it will give me this error : The data source does not support server-side data paging.

this is my code for gridview :

```
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.AllowPaging= true;
        GridView1.DataBind(); 
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: `SqlDataReader` is forward-only. Paging needs backwards and forwards. Use a different datasource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

Comment: may i have an example?

Answer (score 7):

[`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) is forward-only. Server-side Paging needs to be able to traverse the datasource both backward and forward. Use a different datasource, like [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx), which supports bi-directional traversal.

Example (as requested):

```
string query = string.Empty;
SqlConnection conn = null;
SqlCommand cmd = null;
SqlDataAdapter da = null;
DataSet ds = null;

try {
    query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = @value";
    conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string");

    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("value", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "some value";

    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
} catch (SqlException ex) {
//handle exception
} catch (Exception ex) {
//handle exception
} finally {
    if (da != null) {
        da.Dispose();
    }
    if (cmd != null) {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) is also from the `System.Data.SqlClient` Namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataSet/DataTable with your SQL results?  Then use that DataTable as your data source for the GridView.  Basic framework for filling your DataTable:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(String connectionString, String query)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {   

    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

And then you can use that DataTable as your GridView DataSource:

```
String connectionString = "Data Source=<datasource>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User Id=<userID>;Password=<password>;";
String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID=BLAH";

GridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable(connectionString, query);
GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
GridView1.Visible = true;
GridView1.AllowPaging= true;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: when i try this way and implement this in 'GridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable(connectionString, query);' i got these 2 error : connection string does not exist in the current context and query does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Well you have to define your connection string and query variables before you call GetDataTable() :p they are just placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply paging to a gridview in two ways

(1) Use an object datasource with your gridview

(2) Use jquery Datatable